# TExcelApplication - connecting to different servers

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-7

I have 2 excel.exe instances running. How to make my TExcelApplication object to connect to specific excel.exe instance? (I see ConnectTo method but do not understand how to enum running excel com servers)

I'd like to select excel process by PID that I have...

Comment: The obvious answer is to have the PID in a specific cell. Then you can iterate through all Excel instances, connecting to each in turn, looking at the specific cell and see if it contains the PID.

Comment: I need to connect to the excel instance that is currently in the input focus, and what I have for it is PID (and focused window handle of course)... I cannot modify anything in excel sheets, I'm just tracking the time for currently opened sheet in the input focus...